# PHP, SMTP - Subject in email shows International Characters as HTML_Entities

Tags: php, email, utf-8, smtp, encode

I've spent over half a day on this - just trying to get the email Subject to appear normal. But international characters appear as HTML_Entities when the email lands in the inbox.

For example: Tydzień o Jedność

Shows up as: `Tydzie&#324; o Jedno&#347;&#263;`

I already encode the email Subject for UTF-8:

`$this->subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($this->subject) . "?=";`

When I get the email (Gmail), the header appears as:

`Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VHlkemllJiMzMjQ7IG8gSmVkbm8mIzM0NzsmIzI2Mzs=?=`

So it seems to encode properly. But for some reason, Gmail still displays the Subject with HTML_Entities.

Any ideas?

See code: [SMTP mail class](http://mysticpaste.com/view/4096)

Comment: See: http://mysticpaste.com/view/4096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `$this->subject` a valid UTF-8 string? Are you working with UTF-8 encoded .php files (no BOM)?

Also, try doing:

```
$this->subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode(html_entity_decode($this->subject, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')) . "?=";
```

Comment: The problem was - I was using a newsletter mailing script called Simple Mailing List. The form was sent from an html page which lacked meta charset tag. So if you entered foreign characters, when you hit submit, the data would already be scrambled when it arrived in the php file. Adding a meta charset tag set as UTF-8 to the html page that had the form fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd encode the string with

```
$this->subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($this->subject);
```

Using your example string of Tydzień o Jedność, this produces the encoded output

```
=?UTF-8?B?VHlkemllw4XChCBvIEplZG5vw4XCm8OEwoc=?=
```

The Subject header you gave in your question decodes to include the HTML entities:

```
echo mb_decode_mimeheader('=?UTF-8?B?VHlkemllJiMzMjQ7IG8gSmVkbm8mIzM0NzsmIzI2Mzs=?=');
```

gives the string `Tydzie&#324; o Jedno&#347;&#263;`.  Presumably, the string got HTML encoded before it was base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have iconv available, you could try using the [iconv_mime_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-mime-encode.php) function instead of `"=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($this->subject) . "?=";`